# Collecting list of common points

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to do something that is probably simple, but I'm struggling to find a solution.
I have a list of point number pairs (e.g. for point number 343 paired with point number 494 I have a list item named "343/494"). 
The list could look something like this:

```
array(0) = "343/494"
array(1) = "989/282"
array(2) = "343/112"
array(3) = "282/343"
array(4) = "282/9991"
```

What I want to create is a new array with entries that share a common point number, but only have two entries. It would look like the below:

```
new_array(0,0) = "343/494"
new_array(0,1) ="343/112"
```

(note that "282/343" is omitted because there
 is already two entries sharing "343")

```
new_array(1,0) = "989/282"
new_array(1,1) = "282/343"
```

(like the above only two entries are needed containing something with "282")

Since there aren't any unique duplicates of the other values, I don't create put them in the new_array

That's most of what I'm trying to do.

I'd very much appreciate any suggestions

Comment: Are those pairs coming from cell values? And which value has priority for pairing? Where the left value matches or where the pair is closer...?

Comment: unique duplicates is an oxymoron...

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
    Option Explicit

    Sub test()

        Dim arrIni As Variant, arrResult(1) As Variant
        Dim valueIni_1 As String, valueIni_2 As String, valueRes_1 As String, valueRes_2 As String
        Dim i As Long, j As Long, Counter As Long, LastRow As Long

        arrIni = Array("343/494", "989/282", "343/112", "282/343", "282/9991")

        For i = LBound(arrIni) To UBound(arrIni)

            Counter = 0

            valueIni_1 = Split(arrIni(i), "/")(0)
            valueIni_2 = Split(arrIni(i), "/")(1)

            For j = LBound(arrIni) To UBound(arrIni)

                valueRes_1 = Split(arrIni(j), "/")(0)
                valueRes_2 = Split(arrIni(j), "/")(1)

                If (valueIni_1 = valueRes_1) Or (valueIni_1 = valueRes_2) Or (valueIni_2 = valueRes_1) Or (valueIni_2 = valueRes_2) Then

                    Counter = Counter + 1

                    If Counter = 1 Then
                        arrResult(Counter - 1) = arrIni(i)
                    Else
                        arrResult(Counter - 1) = arrIni(j)
                    End If

                    If Counter = 2 Then
                        'Print result in sheet1
                        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

                            LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

                            .Range("A" & LastRow + 2 & ":A" & LastRow + 3).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arrResult)

                        End With

                        Exit For
                    End If

                End If

            Next j

        Next i

    End Sub
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Sorry it took so long to reply to this and thank you. This is really helpful. 
The next step for me is to create a new array of only the duplicate entries. For example, in the above set the new array would only include three entries:

final_array(0) = 343

final_array(1) = 282

final_array(2) = 112

Comment: glad to hear that i help, if the answer if useful please up vote the answer. for the next step i you go through the code is very easy to identify were you should create an additional step to create an array to include unique values.

Comment: Thanks again! I can't up vote though since I don't have enough reputation yet :/